# If another pointer (p) points at a class that was allocated to another pointer (head), will the former (p) invoke a destructor?

Tags: c++

If another pointer (p) points at a class that was allocated to another pointer (head), will the former (p) invoke a destructor? And if it's so, then should I equate (p) to NULL to prevent double destruction of objects?

```
int main()
{
   node* head = new node(1);
   find (head);
   
   //smth

   delete head;
   return 0;
}

void find(node* head)
{
   node* p = head;
   //smth
   //maybe p = NULL
}
```

Comment: If you use raw `new`, your are 100% responsible for managing the object you created. Compiler won't guess when delete needs to be called.

Comment: Thanks, I've adjusted my question.

Comment: Mat answered your question, you don't write `delete p;`, so `p` is not deleted (but `head` is). And indeed, you should not write `delete p;` to avoid the double free.

Comment: Mat, do you mean that destructor in case of allocating memory with new will be invoked only after we write delete?

Comment: Thank you, Jarod, now I've got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete ptr` does two things.  First, it invokes the destructor, based on the type of the pointer `ptr`.  Then it returns the storage used for the object to the free store (aka heap).

In your code you call delete once, so only one destructor is called.  If you called delete twice on the same pointer (or a copy of the pointer), your program executes undefined behaviour (UB).

UB can be a crash, nothing happening, or stranger stuff.

You can split running the destructor from recycling memory in some cases.  But only if you also split allocation from construction.

```
char buff[sizeof(X)];
X* px = ::new( static_cast<void*>(&buff) ) X{};
// use px
// manually destroy *px:
px->~X();
```

this is an advanced technique, don't try it until long after you have learned lessons like "don't use raw pointers".